# MySQL error 1064 when specifying a LIMIT

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT LEFT(c.user_notes, 200) AS user_notes, 
       c.TIME, 
       c.name 
FROM   saved s 
       INNER JOIN chimney c 
         ON c.id = s.can_id 
WHERE  s.user_id = 'admin' 
ORDER  BY lastmodified DESC 
LIMIT  ,10
```

This statement gives me an error:

> err#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10' at line 1

How can this be solved?

Comment: that was some aggressive editing p.campbell - I get the code cleaning but even changing "produces this error" to "This statement gives me this error" and changing how I ask for help at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `,` or use `LIMIT 0, 10`

```
SELECT
  LEFT(c.user_notes,200) AS user_notes,
  c.time,
  c.name
FROM saved s INNER JOIN chimney c ON c.id = s.can_id
WHERE s.user_id='admin' 
ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 0, 10
-------------------------------^^^^
```

Note that 99% of the time, where MySQL complains of invalid syntax is exactly the place where the syntax error occurred.

Comment: eh *sigh*, php is supposed to populate the first variable and I just completely missed that. Polishing off my mysql skills. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Last entry is

```
LIMIT ,10
```

should be

```
LIMIT 10
```

or

```
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma before the `10`. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the comma after `LIMIT`